# All of my app permissions blocked by Android 8.0

Tags: android, permissions

All of my apps permissions worked fine in Android 7.0 Nougat,
But when running the same app on Oreo, I go into the write settings intent, and I see the option to enable it is greyed out.
But this problem occurs for all of my apps permissions and also I cannot read usage access, the app just doesn't show up in the list of apps which have requested access...

When checking the apps permissions from the app details screen, it says no permissions requested.
When trying to force enable the permissions via ADB it says that the permissions have not been requested within the manifest, although they have.

All of this works fine in the same build for Nougat, but has issues in Oreo...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild project?

Comment: Which android version are you targeting on your app?

Comment: I've tried targeting 26 & 27, but no luck... Also I have, cleaned, rebuilt, invalidated cache & restarted. But for some reason it just wont allow my app to use ANY permissions...

Comment: Ok so are you requesting these permissions on runtime?

Comment: Yes. When the users requests a function which requires the app to write settings it will open the write settings management page, but the switch is greyed out...